# Combination of probabilities for probability densities

Tags: probability, distributions, mathematical-statistics, density-function

Say, I have the following experiment: I have a large bucket of some material and I am trying to determine the melt temperature. So I take small samples and put them on a burner and note the temperature when they melt. For some reasons, the melt temperature will not be identical for each small sample but the results will span some continuum and will be distributed with some mean, variance and other moments. I think, I can then talk about a probability distribution, or better about probability density function that the melt temperature of a sample of the same material will be between some $T$ and $T+{\rm d} T$.

I can then talk about a sample having a probability to melt between $T$ and $T+{\rm d} T$. Such probability will be given by $\Pr(\text{melt at }T)\approx f(T)\,{\rm d} T$ or more exactly $\int_T^{T+{\rm d}T}f(x)\,{\rm d} x$ where $f(T)$ is the probability density function.

Then if I randomly select two samples from the bucket, I want to ask: "What is the probability of one of the samples having the melting point between $\{T_1,T_1+{\rm d}T\}$ **AND** he other melts between $(T_2,T_2+{\rm d}T)$?

Is it just $f(T_1)f(T_2)\,{\rm d}T^2$, or more exactly:
$$
\int_{T_1}^{T_1+{\rm d}T} f(x){\rm d} x \int_{T_2}^{T_2+{\rm d}T}f(x)\,{\rm d} x
$$?

But this leads to having new probability distribution functions $f(x)f(y)$ which from what I have read are not necessarily distribution density functions.

Finally, if I take one sample from the bucket, I want to ask about the probability of its melt temperature being between $(T_1, T_1+{\rm d}T)$ **OR** between $(T_2,T_2+{\rm d}T)$, would it be $f(T_1)\,{\rm d}T + f(T_2)\,{\rm d}T$ or more precisely

$$\int_{T_1}^{T_1+{\rm d}T} f(x)\,{\rm d} x + \int_{T_2}^{T_2+{\rm d}T} f(x)\,{\rm d} x\text{?}$$

For discrete probabilities, it works like this, eg. Let's have two hats, in each $l$ red balls, $m$ white balls and $n$ black balls, then the probability of drawing a white ball from both hats is
$$\frac{m}{l+m+n}\times \frac{m}{l+m+n}$$

analogously, the probability of a ball to be black or white after drawing from one hat is:
$$\frac{m}{l+m+n}+\frac{n}{l+m+n}$$. To repeat the question, does this work the same for continuous probabilities as I wrote for the experiment above?

Comment: i'm not sure what exactly you're asking but I _think_ you might be able to answer your question if you work at the level of probability measures rather than densities. It seems like a lot of the confusion here is because of manipulations of differentials and if you just worked with events it might be easier (unless I'm missing what you're trying to do). Have you tried to formulate your question that way, without any densities?

Comment: The sentence "the probability of drawing both black and white is just a multiplication of probabilities of drawing black and white" is unclear but in most cases wrong.

Comment: @Xi'an I agree, one can imagine many things under the sentence but the problem is quite a standard one and I am not sure what you are refering to as wrong. I rewrote the whole question, I hope, this removes all difficulties.

Comment: Your setting (over)complicates two simple questions: (1) what is the chance of two independent events in terms of their individual chances and (2) what is the chance of the union of events?  The answer to (1) is axiomatic--you multiply the chances--while the answer to (2) also is axiomatic and the relevant axioms distinguish between disjoint events and overlapping events.  Thus, its answer depends on whether there is any overlap between the intervals $[T_1,T_1+dT]$ and $[T_2,T_2+dT]$. Please visit https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Probability_axioms for the details.